# How to dynamically change values of CSS variables ONLY in CSS? Is it possible?

Tags: css, css-variables, css-counter

What I mean is, for example, I want to change the value of variable `--color_rgb` every time I increase the counter. What line to add to make it happen?

```css
:root {
  --color_rgb: 50;
}

body {
  counter-set: color 0;
}

p::before {
  counter-increment: color 40;
  content: "Section. " counter(color) " ";
}

p {
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  background-color: rgba(calc(var(--color_rgb)/2), var(--color_rgb), calc(var(--color_rgb)*2), 0.8);
}
```

Comment: can you create a snippet? what are you trying to change the background color for each element ?

Comment: Counters are pseudo-elements, so whatever is assigned as `content` is not part of the DOM. BTW typos: `counter-` **re** `set` and add space on each side of the operators of `calc()` ex. `calc(var(--color_rgb)` `*` `2)`

Comment: Im trying to constantly change the background color of each paragraph by assigning different value to variable..Is there any way to do so in HTML and CSS without JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change a css variable value for particular screensize the it would work with @media queries

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  :root {
    --ball-width: calc(200px);
  }
}
```

it may work in animations but i haven't tried it out yet, so i think you should give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

No. Since counter() returns a string, and you cannot parse a string to a number in CSS. The only way to update your `--color_rgb` by the number of p elements you have is if you add **a lot** of

```
...    
   p:nth-child(20){
     --color-rgb: 60; 
   }
...
```